# How to add a new line without open the fold in VIM

Tags: vim

I fold a function A. Then I want to add a new function at bottom of function A, I known I can press za to toggle the fold of the function A, and add a new line.
The question is that I don't want to open the fold, just add a new line.Can I do this?

Comment: Just type `o` for a new line , you mean that ?

Comment: @buzz I mean I want to add a new line after a fold line.Now I should type `za` to open the fold , then type `o`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I find the problom. Maybe the file content is clearer than my words.

```
vim:fdm=marker:fmr=}}},{{{:fdl=0

# part 1
==Header1}}}1==
    * 123456
    * 123456
    * 123456

# part 2
==Header2}}}1==
    * 123456
    * 123456
    * 123456
{{{
```

First I type `zM` to fold all. When I position my cursor at Header1,type `o` ,the Header1 fold opened . When I position my cursor at Header2,type `o`, the Header2 fold not opened . So I think
I miss the fold end flag `{{{` caused my problem.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your description you want to add a blank line below the first line of a folded block without opening that block. This can be done with the following command:

`:call append('.', '')`  ('.' means the current line).

You can create a normal mode mapping for this like so:

`nnoremap <leader>o :call append('.', '')<cr>`

Or if you want to add more than just an empty line:

`nnoremap <leader>o :call append('.', input('Input line: '))<cr>`

Note that if you were within the fold when you closed it the line will be added below the line you were on.

Comment: Thank you!But It is not my need.I'm sorry for my poor English!